# Modem Manager—Problems with Huawei E5786s-32a

Tags: usb-modem

I have a [Huawei E5786s-32a](http://consumer.huawei.com/kh/support/products/technicalspecs/e5786-kh.htm) WiFi Router which I would like to use as GSM Modem, such that I can send SMS from the computer. If I plug the device via USB to my Laptop (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), run a terminal and type:

```
top
```

I get that:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
1232 root      20   0  337396  10628   6852 R 100,0  0,1   1:08.14 ModemManager
```

So the process has a 100% CPU usage and except increasing fan noise, nothing happens. What can I do to make that work?